Type error when I try to use Redux-Toolkit

userSlice.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create
property 'error' on string 'User created successfully!' at
signInFailure (userSlice.js:22:19) at
@reduxjs_toolkit.js?v=69e8a274:1773:26

Here is my reducer for making requests to API in my MERN application. I'm now encountering issues in Redux-Toolkit slice reducer function.
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  error: null,
  loading: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    signInStart: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    signInSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    },
    signInFailure: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload; // Handle both object and string payloads
      state.loading = false;
    },
});

export const {
  signInStart,
  signInSuccess,
  signInFailure,
  signOutUserStart,
} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;

I tried to make the payload is string but it not solve the problem!
signInFailure: (state, action) => {  
  state.error = typeof action.payload === 'string'
    ? action.payload
    : 'An error occurred';
  state.loading = false; 


We need a complete [mcve]. Can you [edit] to add the code dispatching the actions and what the payload value is that is being passed?

Actually, signInFailure action is being passed a string instead of an object and that causes the attempt to create a property error on the string to fail.
Update the signInFailure reducer to this:
signInFailure: (state, action) => {
  if (typeof action.payload === 'string') {
    state.error = action.payload;
  } else if (action.payload && typeof action.payload.message === 'string') {
    state.error = action.payload.message;
  } else {
    state.error = 'An error occurred';
  }
  state.loading = false;
}

Updated slice:
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  error: null,
  loading: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    signInStart: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    signInSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    },
    signInFailure: (state, action) => {
      if (typeof action.payload === 'string') {
        state.error = action.payload;
      } else if (action.payload && typeof action.payload.message === 'string') {
        state.error = action.payload.message;
      } else {
        state.error = 'An error occurred';
      }
      state.loading = false;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  signInStart,
  signInSuccess,
  signInFailure,
} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;

